# install a packages using python script

Tags: python

Is it possible to  install software using python.py scripts? I wanted the python script to do a sudo command on the Raspberry Pi. I want the python script to be able to update or install a software in the Raspberry Pi just by running the script.

```
def index():

    return sudo apt-get update 

index()
```

where in this case the Raspberry Pi will update when I run the script above.

Comment: thank you for the answer both of you, they are all working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the os module for this purpose. Your sudo command is meant to be entered into a terminal and that is what the `os.system()` function does (it takes your shell command as a string):

```
import os

def install_function():
    os.system('sudo apt-get update')

install_function()
```

You probably will still need to enter your passwort.

If you want to return the answer of your shell command, use `returnstring=os.popen('<your shell command>')`.
But be aware that `os.popen()` does not work with interactive shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
import subprocess

def index():
    subprocess.call("sudo apt-get update", shell=True)

index()
```

Comment: In what ways would this be different or potentially better? I'm trying to learn how to issue commands from within a Python script (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/80271/35753) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/80219/35753)) and having some problems. I wonder if `subprocess` might be better in my case as well.